# how to get unique records from 2 javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays. Which has few common values. I want to filter out those items. I tried `es6` `indexOf` and `includes` operators but no luck.

```js
arr1 = [ 
["Test1", 20, "table", "Sample1", "NA"], 
["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
["Test3", 20, "table", "Sample3", "NA"],
["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"]
];

arr2 = [
["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"],
["Test6", 20, "table", "Sample6", "NA"],
["Test7", 20, "table", "Sample7", "NA"]
];

let unique = arr2.filter((item, i, ar) => arr1.indexOf(item) === -1);

console.log(unique); //returns all 5

   let result = [...arr1, ...unique];

   console.log('length is:', result.length); //length should be 7 but its 10
```

Comment: So you want a result array that contains elements that exist in either one array or the other, but not both?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want unique records from those two arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a Set of the stringified sub-arrays. Filter both arrays by whether the current stringified sub-array is contained in the *other* array's Set:

```js
const arr1 = [ 
  ["Test1", 20, "table", "Sample1", "NA"], 
  ["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
  ["Test3", 20, "table", "Sample3", "NA"],
  ["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
  ["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"]
];

const arr2 = [
  ["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
  ["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
  ["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"],
  ["Test6", 20, "table", "Sample6", "NA"],
  ["Test7", 20, "table", "Sample7", "NA"]
];

const set1 = new Set(arr1.map(JSON.stringify));
const set2 = new Set(arr2.map(JSON.stringify));

const unique1 = arr1.filter(subarr => !set2.has(JSON.stringify(subarr)));
const unique2 = arr2.filter(subarr => !set1.has(JSON.stringify(subarr)));

console.log(unique1);
console.log(unique2);
```

I'm turning the arrays into Sets to reduce the computational complexity - `Set#has` is `O(1)`, but array methods for the same logic are `O(n)`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is technically `O(n)` as well (where `n` is the length of the array elements under comparison).

Comment: Yes, but it only has to be done *once* per sub-array - the alternative method involving examining each of the other's sub arrays inside a `.filter` is an order of n more complex

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
To get unique elements, go thru both arrays and build one object and use `Object.values` to convert to array of arrays.

```js
arr1 = [
  ["Test1", 20, "table", "Sample1", "NA"],
  ["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
  ["Test3", 20, "table", "Sample3", "NA"],
  ["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
  ["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"]
];

arr2 = [
  ["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
  ["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
  ["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"],
  ["Test6", 20, "table", "Sample6", "NA"],
  ["Test7", 20, "table", "Sample7", "NA"]
];



const assign = (array, obj) =>
  array.forEach(arr => Object.assign(obj, { [arr.join()]: arr }));

const res = {};
assign(arr1, res);
assign(arr2, res);

const unique = Object.values(res);

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: I want unique items from those two arrays. This is returning items which are not unique in `arr2`. I tried adding `!==`. But its returning all the records from `arr2` not sure why

Comment: @NareshShetty, my bad, Now updated to get values from both arrays which have unique values. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By using the below commonElements() function you can get the desired output.

```html
arr1 = [
      ["Test1", 20, "table", "Sample1", "NA"],
      ["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
      ["Test3", 20, "table", "Sample3", "NA"],
      ["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
      ["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"]
    ];

    arr2 = [
      ["Test2", 20, "table", "Sample2", "NA"],
      ["Test4", 20, "table", "Sample4", "NA"],
      ["Test5", 20, "table", "Sample5", "NA"],
      ["Test6", 20, "table", "Sample6", "NA"],
      ["Test7", 20, "table", "Sample7", "NA"]
    ];

    function notcommonElements(arr1, arr2) {
        var obj = {}, matched = [],
            unmatched = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = arr1.length; i < l; i++) {
            obj[arr1[i]] = (obj[arr1[i]] || 0) + 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            var val = arr2[i];
            if (val in obj) {
                matched.push(val);
            } else {
                unmatched.push(val);
            }
        }
        console.log(unmatched);
    }

    notcommonElements(arr1, arr2);
```